How to declare dependency on specific branch in libs.versions.toml
What would be the equivalent of:

dependency("com.example:dep") {
    version {
        branch = "1.0.0"
    }
}


when declaring a dependency in libs.versions.toml?
The following:
[versions]
depVersion = { branch = "1.0.0" }

[libraries]
dep = { module = "com.example:dep", version.ref = "depVersion" }

doesn't seem to work
